# React material-table is not displaying table icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have a project where I have to use a table. I am using material-table. But I can't seem to get it to look right. The icons that are needed for the table are not showing and instead I get some placeholder texts.

Here is the code I am using to show the table. I have material-table and material-icons installed in the project.

```
class RegistrationList extends Component {
  state = {
    registrations: [],
  };

  infoButtonHandler(id) {}

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3030/api/items").then((res) => {
      let registrations = [];
      res.data.forEach((registration) => {
        let childeren = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < registration.childeren.length; i++) {
          childeren += registration.childeren[i].name;
          if (i + 1 !== registration.childeren.length) {
            childeren += ", ";
          }
        }
        registrations.push({
          _id: registration._id,
          name: registration.name,
          childeren: childeren,
          street: registration.street,
          houseNumber: registration.houseNumber,
          city: registration.city,
          postalCode: registration.postalCode,
        });
      });
      this.setState({ registrations: registrations });
    });
  }

  rowClickedHandler(rowData) {
    this.props.history.push("/RegistrationDetail/" + rowData._id);
  }

  render() {
    let table = (
      <MaterialTable
        title="Overzicht"
        columns={[
          { title: "familienaam", field: "name" },
          { title: "kinderen", field: "childeren" },
          { title: "dorp", field: "city" },
          { title: "postcode", field: "postalCode" },
          { title: "straat", field: "street" },
          { title: "nr.", field: "houseNumber" },
        ]}
        data={this.state.registrations}
        options={{
          search: true,
        }}
        onRowClick={(event, rowData) => this.rowClickedHandler(rowData)}
      />
    );
    return <div>{table}</div>;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It says right on the site what to do [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/install)

Add material icons
There are two ways to use icons in material-table either import the material icons font via html OR import material icons and use the material-table icons prop.

HTML

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
/>
```

OR

Import Material icons
Icons can be imported to be used in material-table offering more flexibility for customising the look and feel of material table over using a font library.

To install @material-ui/icons with npm:

```
npm install @material-ui/icons --save
```

To install @material-ui/icons with yarn:

```
yarn add @material-ui/icons
```

If your environment doesn't support tree-shaking, the recommended way to import the icons is the following:

```
import AddBox from "@material-ui/icons/AddBox";
import ArrowDownward from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward";
```

If your environment support tree-shaking you can also import the icons this way:

```
import { AddBox, ArrowDownward } from "@material-ui/icons";
```

Note: Importing named exports in this way will result in the code for every icon being included in your project, so is not recommended unless you configure tree-shaking. It may also impact Hot Module Reload performance. Source: @material-ui/icons

Example

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

import AddBox from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ArrowDownward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward';
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import ChevronLeft from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import DeleteOutline from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import FilterList from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';
import FirstPage from '@material-ui/icons/FirstPage';
import LastPage from '@material-ui/icons/LastPage';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';
import SaveAlt from '@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';

const tableIcons = {
    Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
    DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
    FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
    SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
  };

<MaterialTable
  icons={tableIcons}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: You need to import `'forwardRef'` for this to work, otherwise error: `'forwardRef' is not defined `

Answer (score 9):

this approach is working for me

```
 import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';

actions={[
        
        rowData => ({
          icon: DeleteIcon,
          tooltip: 'Delete User',
          onClick: (event, rowData) => confirm("You want to delete " + rowData.name),
          disabled: rowData.birthYear < 2000
        })
      ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade material UI to @material-ui/core@4.2.1 by yarn add @material-ui/core@4.2.1 and hopefully, it will work

Answer (score 1):

To get them working, I added them manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
import and add icon to tableIcons.js file
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';

AddNew: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddIcon {...props} ref={ref} />),
```

import into the file where you need the icon

```
import tableIcons from "components/Table/tableIcons";
```

use with bellow code where needed

```
 icon: tableIcons.AddNew,
```